# App is crashing when trying to record audio on setOnTouchListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener, touch-event, android-audiorecord

This Question is already asked but I am unable to find out my solution .

What i am doing is, `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` of `OnTouchListener` I started  recording audio and in `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` I stopped audio recording.

During long touch of that icon it is working fine but `onclick` app is crashing.
Here is my

```
audio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(Chat.this, "You Have to hold the Button for audio recording.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

audio.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                MediaRecorderReady();
                try {
                    mediaRecorder.prepare();
                    mediaRecorder.start();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (mediaRecorder != null) {
                    mediaRecorder.stop();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

 public void MediaRecorderReady() {
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(AudioSavePathInDevice);
}
```

Here is my problem , when I am clicking on that button the app is crashing

Comment: post your error logs here

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.                                                                                   at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)

Comment: kindly put the complete logcat and check that when you press onclick onTouch is called ActionDown and ActionUp is also called.

Comment: yes thats why it is crashing but how to solve this

Comment: i have posted the answer to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this answer
[Android mediarecorder stop failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147563/android-mediarecorder-stop-failed)
and Also Read the offical documentation about mediaRecorder and its states.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html
crash is caused because you stop the media player and media player not in recording state..
donot call stop directly when it is not in recording state.

```
try {
     mRecorder.stop();
    } 
     catch(RuntimeException e) {
     } 
      finally {
               mRecorder.release();
               mRecorder = null;
     }
```

Comment: Thank you. this try catch block solved crashing app .

Comment: Can you tell me how to show a toast when i just click on the button and audio will record in press down for long time ?

Answer (score 0):

do like below.

```
private MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder;
    private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

audio.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                initializeRecorder();                  
                recordFile(); 

            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                stopRecording();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

private void initializeRecorder() {
        File cacheDir = new File(Utils.SD_CARD, Utils.RECORDING_CACHE);
        if (!(cacheDir.exists())) {
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
        }

        outputFile = cacheDir + "/" + String.format("%s.m4a", System.currentTimeMillis());

        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

        //original
        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

    }

private void recordFile() {
        try {
            myAudioRecorder.prepare();
            myAudioRecorder.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }

private void stopRecording(){
     myAudioRecorder.stop();
     myAudioRecorder.release();
}
```

Comment: My code is working fine when i touch for long time and then remove

Comment: then what is issue?

Comment: when i just touch the audio button then app is crashing. On long press and release the audio is recording  fine